# Order by Age Range in MySql Using Age Units

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table:

```
Id   User       Event    Age     Age_Unit
1    Jonathan   aaa      5       2 
2    Frank      bbb      15      1
3    Karen      ccc      42      1
4    Yamile     ddd      20      3
```

I need to group by age range:

0-4 Years

5-10 Years

11-15 Years

16-20 Years

21-25 Years

26-30 Years

...etc

Having Age_Unit:

1 = Years

2 = Months

3 = Days

The final table would be

```
    Id   User       Event    Age     Age_Unit  Range
    1    Jonathan   aaa      5       2         0-1
    2    Frank      bbb      15      1         11-15
    3    Karen      ccc      42      1         40-45
    4    Yamile     ddd      20      3         0-1
```

I am using this query:

```
SELECT `Age`, `Age_Unit`, 
CASE WHEN `Age_Unit` > 1 THEN "0-1"
WHEN `Age_Unit` = 1 THEN "Older than 1" 
ELSE NULL END AS Age_Range
FROM table1 as fe
```

I don't know how to integrate all the age range.

Comment: Why not store the "age unit" as the age unit!?!?!

Comment: Hi, @Strawberry, It would be:  Age :2  Age_unit: 1

Comment: Sorry, I edited the age range :)

Comment: This is an oddball way to store ages. Seems like it would be easier to store the birthdate and the event_date. Or store the age in days in a single column.

Comment: I know, I didn't create the table and I need to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.id
     , x.user
     , x.event
     , x.age
     , x.age_unit
     , CASE WHEN years BETWEEN  0 AND 4 THEN '0-4'
                  WHEN years BETWEEN  5 AND 10 THEN '5-10'
                  WHEN years BETWEEN 11 AND 15 THEN '11-15'
                  WHEN years BETWEEN 16 AND 20 THEN '16-20'
                  WHEN years BETWEEN 21 AND 25 THEN '21-15'
                  WHEN years BETWEEN 26 AND 30 THEN '26-30'
                  ELSE 'old' END `range`
  FROM
     ( SELECT *
            , CASE age_unit 
              WHEN 3 
              THEN age/365 
              WHEN 2 
              THEN age/12 
              ELSE age 
              END years 
         FROM my_table
     ) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change all of your `Age`s into days, then sort by that:

```
SELECT `Age`,
    `Age_Unit`,
    CASE 
        WHEN age_days < 1825
            THEN "0-4"
        WHEN age_days BETWEEN 365 AND 3650
            THEN "5-10"
        etc...
        ELSE NULL
        END AS Age_Range
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            user, 
            event,
            Age,
            Age_Unit,
            `Age` / CASE 
                WHEN `Age_Unit` = 1 THEN 365
                WHEN `Age_Unit` = 2 THEN 12
                WHEN `Age_Unit` = 3 Then 1
                END as age_days
    )
ORDER BY
    age_days asc
```

**Editted** to add the bracketing using the days. The number of days old the person is figured in the subquery and then used for both the bracketing and the order by.

Comment: I am going to try it, But I need the age_range by Years

Comment: This doesn't change your `age_range`. It just determines the number of days old the person is and then uses that as the `ORDER BY` for the result set.

Comment: Just edited to add the bracketing in using this idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use php to do that

eg :

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=age;host=localhost';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root');
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT age, age_unit FROM ages');
$results = $query->fetchAll();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
    $range = '0 - 1';
    if ($results[$i]['age_unit'] === '1') {
        $age = $results[$i]['age'];
        $first = substr($age, 0, 1);
        $min = $first . "0";
        $max = $first . "5";

        $range = $min . " - " . $max;
    }

    $results[$i]['range'] = $range;
}

var_dump($results);
```